# Move login link to right side of the navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to move my Login button to the right side of the Navbar.
Here's what I have right now. I managed to move the login button to the right side however, It is not aligned correctly along with the left side of the navbar menu tabs. Thank you so much for your help.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-01">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="fui-flat"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-01">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">           
                <li class="active"><a href="#fakelink">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#fakelink">Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#fakelink">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#fakelink">About</a></li>  
              </ul>  
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-01">    
                  <ul class="nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </nav><!-- /navbar -->
```

Comment: Can you show us some CSS? Or is bootstrap that different from regular web dev?

Answer (score 2):

Just add class `navbar-nav`. [**Working Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/rRRIvLzIq4)

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with class `pull-right`.

```
<ul class="pull-right nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```